# Change Default Printer within WPF Application

Tags: c#, wpf, printing, wmi

I'm looking for the best approach to change the default printer within a WPF application. Here are the steps the we're hoping the application can do.

1. Select a location from a drop down which is mapped to a printer name.
2. Change the default printer to the mapped name.
3. Launch IE and point to SSRS report.
4. User will then print report from IE, which will use the new default printer

Step two is what I'm looking for assistance with.

Is this a use case for WMI? If so, any resources on the subject would be a huge help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

use  this:

```
var query = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_Printer"); 
var printers = query.Get();
string printerName = "Printer to set as default" ;
foreach(ManagementObject printer in printers) 
{ 
   if (printer["name"].ToString() == printerName.ToString()) 
   { 
      printer.InvokeMethod("SetDefaultPrinter", new object[] { printerName }); 
   } 
}
```

Comment: I added a reference to System.Management and System.Management.Instrumentation and added an import 'using System.Management;'. However, I'm still getting error lines under 'currentObject' and 'InvokeMethod'. I'm guessing that 'currentObject' actual needs to be 'printer', but that still doesn't resolve the 'InvokeMethod' issue.

Comment: I'm getting an error trying to call InvokeMethod on the printer object:

'System.Management.ManagementBaseObject' does not contain a definition for 'InvokeMethod' and no extension method 'InvokeMethod' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Management.ManagementBaseObject' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Ah. We can't use "var printer" here because it resovles to the the ManagementBaseObject which does not have InvokeMethod available. When I change 'var' to 'ManagementObject' it works just fine.